# formula or macro for finding max value

Tags: excel, vba

I have a 2 column excel sheet, Column 1 has a list of email addresses, and column 2 has a list of dates they attended an event.  The same email address can be on different rows if they have attended multiple events.

What I need to do is identify the last event date associated with an email address.  For email addresses that are repeated on multiple rows what is the best way to identify the last date?

Comment: A pivot table could do this

Answer (score 2):

Without sorting the data you can use an array formula. Column E has a list of unique email addresses. Put this in F2.

```
=MAX(IF($A$2:$A$1000=E2,$B$2:$B$1000,0))
```

The formula must be confirmed with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd> Copy down.

As a one-off alternative, copy the two columns to a new place. Sort by date in descending order (newest on top). Then use Data > Remove Duplicates and select only the email. This will result in a list with all email addresses and the latest date for each email address.

The Pivot table, as hinted above works if you pull the email into the row panel, the date into the values panel and then change the Value Field Settings to summarize values by "Max". Then format the result as a date.